# assign a templated variable at runtime

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, constexpr

I have some code that worked great until now but there is a new change that is breaking it. Looking for ideas on how to deal with it. I am not a C++ template expert and have basic working knowledge.

```
namespace foo {
enum {
A1,
A2,
..
AN
};

constexpr int A = 
#if defined(SOME_DEFINE1)
A1,
#elif defined(SOME_DEFINE2)
A2,
...
#elif defined(SOME_DEFINEN)
AN
#endif
;

// Then I have some variables that depend on A
template<int> struct var1;
template<>struct var1<A1> { static constexpr auto value = v1; }
template<>struct var1<A2> { static constexpr auto value = v2; }
template<>struct var1<A3> { static constexpr auto value = v3; }

template<int> struct var2;
template<>struct var2<A1> { static constexpr auto value = x1; }
template<>struct var2<A2> { static constexpr auto value = x2; }
template<>struct var2<A3> { static constexpr auto value = x3; }
} // namespace foo

constexpr auto VAR1 = foo::var1<foo::A>::value;
constexpr auto VAR2 = foo::var2<foo::A>::value;
```

now VAR1 and VAR2 are used in multiple places. I understand that all of this code will be optimized by the compiler and things work.

Now because of the new change I can only know the value of 'A' at runtime and as a result cannot declare is at constant anymore. A will be determined from a value of a global variable somewhere. Any ideas on how to implement this so I make very minimal changes to my code.

Let us say there is a gVal which can be 1,2 or 3 and based on that I want to set A to be A1,A2 or A3 which affect the values of other variables. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `var1` and `var2` are not variables, yet you define them with `=` signs as if they are. Your code can't compile.

Comment: sorry that's a typo. no '=' sign for var1, var2...etc

Comment: you can't have template are runtime, they are evaluated at compile time. Your VAR1 and VAR2 are constexpr, so you'll have to review *ALL* your code if you change that.

Comment: Essentially, if `A` is determined at run time, `VAR1`, etc can no longer be determined using template machinery - which is completed/evaluated at compile time, so cannot be deferred to run time.  I'd probably just write a function to map the possible values of `foo::A` to the desired result. Depending on a lot of other details of your code (which you haven't shown) it is possible that function could be `constexpr` - which means, if it is passed a constant known at compile time, it can be evaluated at compile time. If that's possible, you can eliminate parts of the template machinery.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three sane approaches.

1. Rewrite into constexpr functions piece by piece, unit testing all the way, keeping old version intact.  Then swap to runtime version of the constexpr functions.
2. Wrap your program (or piece of the program) in a big template that takes `A` as an argument.  Instantiate one of these templates for each valid `A`.  Write an interface to this that picks which one of these massive template instances to use.
3. Treat this as reimplementing code in another language.  Use the existing code as a basis, but don't reuse it.  Compile-time C++ isn't that similar to runtime C++.

In my opinion: 2 is the fastest, 3 requires the least skill to make progress, and 1 takes the longest but is least likely to introduce new regressions.